# Select only 5 random rows in the last 50 entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm just starting with MySQL so I would like to know how can I `select` only 5 random rows in the last 50 entries of my database? I hope you understand my question.

I'm using PDO and what I have now is this:

```
$otherChoiseRig = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE cat = '$ArtCat' ORDER BY RAND()  ");
 $otherChoiseRig2 =  $otherChoiseRig->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then I use a PHP foreach loop...

Thank you

Comment: You want random 5 rows across the tables ?

Comment: Yes but only in the las 50 entries

Comment: Whether all the tables are having similar table structure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is determining the last 50 entries.  Assuming you have an auto-incremented id, you can do:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*
      FROM articulos a
      WHERE cat = '$ArtCat'
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 50
     ) a
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 5;
```

The key idea is the subquery to get the last 50 entries, and then the final query to get the 5 random rows.  The subquery needs to specify how you identify the last 50.

Comment: @Boris it's called an alias. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: @Boris Ask Gordon; it's his answer.

Comment: Solved! Thank you @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Boris I noticed you deleted your comment about the PDO error. Glad it worked out for you, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

just add limit

i assume in your table you have some date column so we can get last 50

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE cat = '$ArtCat' ORDER BY created_tiem desc limit 50 ) t order by RAND()  limit 5;

Comment: This will select 5 rands on all the data base

Comment: i assume you have created_time or some column to get last 50 order

Answer (score 0):

```
$otherChoiseRig = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE cat = '$ArtCat' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5 ");
$otherChoiseRig2 =  $otherChoiseRig->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```